# How to properly use lme4 and emmeans to perform contrasts on a population basis across a variable with 2 levels (treatment yes vs no)

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, emmeans, contrast

For some context, I have detected some cell populations and their associated counts in my cytometry data samples using [FAUST](https://github.com/RGLab/FAUST).

I have some meta information that groups my samples into treatment groups (just Treatment "Yes" or "No").

Now I want to fit a mixed model with `lme4::glmer` on my counts data, and perform contrasts for each cell population, to see if they are significantly over-represented in the "Yes" treatment group over the "No" treatment group (probably using `emmeans`).

I'm not very familiar with linear models and model contrasts. I followed the last steps in [this FAUST vignette](https://github.com/RGLab/FAUST/blob/master/vignettes/faustPFDA.Rmd) (scroll all the way to the bottom).

Up to the `lme4::glmer` step it all looks fine, but I'm not sure how to perform the contrasts here. `multcomp::glht` as in the vignette does not give me the results that I want (ie: p-values and fold change for each cell population contrast across the treatment levels).

I know there are a lot of questions and references, but the more I read the more confused I get... Any help is appreciated, I feel like I'm almost there.

I have made a MWE starting from what my counts data looks like.

```
count_mat <- matrix(c(234,1287,234,1174,34,2285,7,7,
                      1157,779,45,572,293,3090,83,76,
                      124,1097,3,829,18,235,366,322,
                      341,1526,3,364,97,593,192,215,
                      378,330,18,960,20,293,204,197,
                      113,174,20,204,5,67,538,469,
                      14,552,2,464,3,25,911,978,
                      317,302,24,763,89,2791,71,55,
                      47,541,4,778,16,361,314,261,
                      322,192,14,1099,30,434,216,217,
                      120,231,18,829,24,812,97,83,
                      6,229,1,555,2,78,952,904,
                      88,628,0,1599,19,159,609,508,
                      1122,640,29,374,0,143,0,0,
                      1374,77,1884,688,0,289,5,2,
                      308,74,475,856,84,477,263,215,
                      59,0,2,508,1,0,0,1,
                      45,106,185,106,0,29,10,3,
                      7,142,30,61,0,12,54,28,
                      3,88,6,41,1,13,148,84,
                      4,51,2,44,0,3,115,80,
                      0,31,0,214,0,1,1281,1082,
                      0,24,0,225,0,1,1330,1057,
                      10,43,0,1412,1,19,806,624,
                      639,137,1108,1604,0,205,9,6,
                      96,767,8,587,1,59,28,11,
                      290,343,709,3666,10,668,511,335,
                      70,383,0,384,0,7,11,3,
                      160,149,297,3790,3,85,682,560,
                      49035,80096,23418,215461,3822,52535,62579,53099),
                    nrow=8, ncol=30)
colnames(count_mat) <- c(paste0('Pop_', 1:29), 'Pop_0')
rownames(count_mat) <- paste0('Samp_', 1:8)
cell_pops <- setdiff(colnames(count_mat), "Pop_0")
count_mat <- cbind(count_mat, parent_count=rowSums(count_mat))
count_df <- data.frame(ID=rownames(count_mat), as.data.frame(count_mat))
rownames(count_df) <- NULL
#
meta_info <- data.frame(ID=paste0('Samp_', 1:8), Treatment=c('Yes','Yes','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No'), Patient=paste0('Pat_', 1:8))
count_df <- dplyr::inner_join(count_df, meta_info, by="ID")
```

This is what `counts_df` looks like:

```
> count_df
      ID Pop_1 Pop_2 Pop_3 Pop_4 Pop_5 Pop_6 Pop_7 Pop_8 Pop_9 Pop_10 Pop_11 Pop_12 Pop_13 Pop_14 Pop_15 Pop_16 Pop_17
1 Samp_1   234  1157   124   341   378   113    14   317    47    322    120      6     88   1122   1374    308     59
2 Samp_2  1287   779  1097  1526   330   174   552   302   541    192    231    229    628    640     77     74      0
3 Samp_3   234    45     3     3    18    20     2    24     4     14     18      1      0     29   1884    475      2
4 Samp_4  1174   572   829   364   960   204   464   763   778   1099    829    555   1599    374    688    856    508
5 Samp_5    34   293    18    97    20     5     3    89    16     30     24      2     19      0      0     84      1
6 Samp_6  2285  3090   235   593   293    67    25  2791   361    434    812     78    159    143    289    477      0
7 Samp_7     7    83   366   192   204   538   911    71   314    216     97    952    609      0      5    263      0
8 Samp_8     7    76   322   215   197   469   978    55   261    217     83    904    508      0      2    215      1
  Pop_18 Pop_19 Pop_20 Pop_21 Pop_22 Pop_23 Pop_24 Pop_25 Pop_26 Pop_27 Pop_28 Pop_29  Pop_0 parent_count Treatment
1     45      7      3      4      0      0     10    639     96    290     70    160  49035        56483       Yes
2    106    142     88     51     31     24     43    137    767    343    383    149  80096        91019       Yes
3    185     30      6      2      0      0      0   1108      8    709      0    297  23418        28539       Yes
4    106     61     41     44    214    225   1412   1604    587   3666    384   3790 215461       240211        No
5      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      0      1     10      0      3   3822         4573        No
6     29     12     13      3      1      1     19    205     59    668      7     85  52535        65769       Yes
7     10     54    148    115   1281   1330    806      9     28    511     11    682  62579        72392        No
8      3     28     84     80   1082   1057    624      6     11    335      3    560  53099        61482        No
  Patient
1   Pat_1
2   Pat_2
3   Pat_3
4   Pat_4
5   Pat_5
6   Pat_6
7   Pat_7
8   Pat_8
```

Then I turn the data into long format with only some selected cell populations:

```
sel_cell_pops <- cell_pops[c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29)]
glmer_df <- count_df[,c("ID", sel_cell_pops, "parent_count", "Treatment", "Patient")]
glmer_df <- tidyr::gather(glmer_df, key=pop_name, value=count, -c("ID", "parent_count", "Treatment", "Patient"))
glmer_df$pop_name <- as.factor(glmer_df$pop_name)
glmer_df$obs_factor <- as.factor(paste0("Obs_", seq(nrow(glmer_df))))
glmer_df$Patient <- factor(glmer_df$Patient, levels=gtools::mixedsort(unique(glmer_df$Patient)))
glmer_df$Treatment <- factor(glmer_df$Treatment, levels=gtools::mixedsort(unique(glmer_df$Treatment)))
#set reference level (not needed)
glmer_df$Treatment <- stats::relevel(glmer_df$Treatment, ref=levels(glmer_df$Treatment)[1])
#my reference level here for Treatment is "No"
#comparisons would be Treatment Yes vs No for each population
#
#do these on the fly calculation here or emmeans complains
glmer_df$parent_count2 <- glmer_df$parent_count - glmer_df$count
```

This is what `glmer_df` (the data that goes into my linear model) looks like

```
> head(glmer_df)
      ID parent_count Treatment Patient pop_name count obs_factor parent_count2
1 Samp_1        56483       Yes   Pat_1    Pop_2  1157      Obs_1         55326
2 Samp_2        91019       Yes   Pat_2    Pop_2   779      Obs_2         90240
3 Samp_3        28539       Yes   Pat_3    Pop_2    45      Obs_3         28494
4 Samp_4       240211        No   Pat_4    Pop_2   572      Obs_4        239639
5 Samp_5         4573        No   Pat_5    Pop_2   293      Obs_5          4280
6 Samp_6        65769       Yes   Pat_6    Pop_2  3090      Obs_6         62679
```

Now I fit the model. Here I have my first question: I specify `(1|Patient)` as random effect in my model, but in the FAUST vignette I follow, they do `(1|obs_factor)`; what would be more appropriate with my data?

```
#fit the model
glmer_fit <- lme4::glmer(
  formula=cbind(count, parent_count2) ~ pop_name*Treatment + (1|Patient), #should this be (1|obs_factor)?
  data=glmer_df,
  family="binomial",
  nAGQ=0,
  control=lme4::glmerControl(
    optimizer="bobyqa",
    optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e9),
    boundary.tol = 1e-9,
    tolPwrss=1e-9,
    check.conv.singular = lme4::.makeCC(action = "warning",  tol = 1e-12)
  )
)
```

This is where I have trouble, I use `emmeans` as I saw in other questions, but I don't make sense of the result

```
em_result <- emmeans::emmeans(glmer_fit, ~ pop_name*Treatment)
contrast_result <- emmeans::contrast(em_result, interaction = "pairwise")
```

This is what I get:

```
> head(contrast_result)
 pop_name_pairwise Treatment_pairwise estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Pop_10 - Pop_11   No - Yes              0.621 0.0592 Inf  10.484  <.0001
 Pop_10 - Pop_12   No - Yes             -1.560 0.0728 Inf -21.440  <.0001
 Pop_10 - Pop_13   No - Yes             -0.659 0.0566 Inf -11.638  <.0001
 Pop_10 - Pop_16   No - Yes              0.426 0.0561 Inf   7.587  <.0001
 Pop_10 - Pop_17   No - Yes             -1.640 0.1416 Inf -11.583  <.0001
 Pop_10 - Pop_19   No - Yes              0.775 0.1180 Inf   6.564  <.0001

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.
```

But since what I want is to test each population individually to see if it's `greater` in Treatment "Yes" vs "No", I would expect something more like:

```
 pop_name Treatment_pairwise estimate     SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Pop_1    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Pop_2    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Pop_3    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Pop_4    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Pop_5    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 Pop_6    Yes - No           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How should I accomplish this? A line per cell population with it's contrast for Treatment "Yes" (`greater`) vs "No", with p-values and fold change if possible.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I think I might have figured the right `contrast` commands, as the outputs seem closer to what I want... are these correct for my purposes?

```
#1
em_result1 <- emmeans::emmeans(glmer_fit, ~ Treatment | pop_name)
contrast_result1 <- emmeans::contrast(em_result1, interaction = "pairwise", adjust = "bh")
#2
em_result2 <- emmeans::emmeans(glmer_fit, ~ pop_name*Treatment)
contrast_result2 <- emmeans::contrast(em_result2, "consec", simple = "Treatment", combine = TRUE, adjust = "bh")
```

The results seem identical, just with Treatment levels "flipped" (why is that?). I'm leaning more towards `#2` as "Yes vs No" seems "more correct" given that "No" is my reference level...

```
> head(contrast_result1)
 Treatment_pairwise pop_name estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 No - Yes           Pop_10      0.357 0.221 Inf   1.616  0.1592
 No - Yes           Pop_11     -0.264 0.221 Inf  -1.195  0.2785
 No - Yes           Pop_12      1.917 0.225 Inf   8.513  <.0001
 No - Yes           Pop_13      1.015 0.220 Inf   4.606  <.0001
 No - Yes           Pop_16     -0.069 0.220 Inf  -0.313  0.7543
 No - Yes           Pop_17      1.997 0.256 Inf   7.806  <.0001

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: BH method for 6 tests 
> head(contrast_result2)
 contrast pop_name estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Yes - No Pop_10     -0.357 0.221 Inf  -1.616  0.1592
 Yes - No Pop_11      0.264 0.221 Inf   1.195  0.2785
 Yes - No Pop_12     -1.917 0.225 Inf  -8.513  <.0001
 Yes - No Pop_13     -1.015 0.220 Inf  -4.606  <.0001
 Yes - No Pop_16      0.069 0.220 Inf   0.313  0.7543
 Yes - No Pop_17     -1.997 0.256 Inf  -7.806  <.0001

Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: BH method for 6 tests
```

So would this be the right way to do it for my purposes?

**NOTE:**

I read somewhere that, because this is a mixed model, I should run `confint` on the `emmeans` result... how should I integrate this?

Thanks!